# Mobile_Detect.php switch to desktop

Tags: mobile, web, mobile-website

I have issue with switching to desktop, I`m using Mobile_Detect.php script and detection for mobile is working fine, here is the code

```
    inc.header.php (Desktop site)

if ($_GET['v'] == 'desktop') {

   $_SESSION["v1"] = 'desktop';


}
// Detect browser and redirect mobile users unless they've already opted out
if ($_SESSION["v1"] != 'desktop') {
    // Place browser detection and redirection code here
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$objMobile = new Mobile_Detect;
if($objMobile ->isMobile()) {

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/")
    {

   header('Location: http://www.website.com/m/');
    }
else
    {
 header("Location: http://www.website.com/m".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    exit;
}
}
```

Mobile setting is following

```
files :

**inc.footer.php** 

if ($_GET['v'] == 'desktop') {

   $_SESSION["v1"] = 'desktop';


}

**footer.html**

<a href="http://website.com/?v=desktop">Desktop version</a></div>
```

What`s interesting switching to desktop is working when I`m browsing on desktop computer but when I`m trying to switch from mobile it`s direct me to http://website.com/m/?v=desktop but not switching to desktop

Your help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Anyone who can help ?

Comment: Guys anyone who could help on this ?